# PHP, MySQL performance and efficiency scenario

Tags: php, mysql, performance

**Simplified scenario:**

1. I have a table with about 100,000 rows.
2. I will need to pick about 300-400 rows, based on certain criteria, to display them on a web page.

**Considering the above scenario, which one of the below approaches will you recommend?**

*Approach 1*: Use just one database query to select the entire table into one big array of 100,000 rows. Using loops, pick required 300-400 rows from the array and pass it one to the front-end. Minimum load on the database server, as it's just one query. Put's more load on the PHP, as it has to store and search through an array of 100,000.

*Approach 2*: Using a loop, PHP will generate a new query for each row of required data. Collecting all the data will require 300-400 independent queries. More load on the server. Compared to approach 1, lesser load on PHP.

Opinions / thoughts will be appreciated!

Comment: Why don't you use just MySQL to query the database and just use PHP to display the data?

Comment: The right approach is : Call a SQL query which return the exact rows you want and let PHP cares about the displaying.

Comment: I would never recommend approach 2. Do you know what kind of data are you going to fetch. Is the data in specific order or just randomly ordered?

Comment: As sdespont suggested, it is better to know what rows to fetch (as you said, based on certain criteria). So you basically have to set up your database to work like that. Even if that means more than one table.

Comment: if you can search the data with php, you can write a query to get the right data to use in the first place.

Comment: The data is randomly ordered. Each row will identified based on a unique ID. Hence, to fetch the exact data that I want, I can only fetch one row at a time. This will result in 300-400 separate small queries. Will this be a better approach than approach 1?

Comment: you still haven't explained why you cant select the rows you want in one query in the first place.

Comment: @Dagon The table that I'm querying was not built for the type of queries I'm attempting right now. The piece of data that'll decide whether the row is required or not is hidden beneath a JSON string inside a particular field. That's why I can't query the database directly.

Comment: i would consider extracting the data you need in a loop to write to a new table column, you really are doing it the hard way otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

100,000 rows is a small amount for MySQL rdbms.

You would better do fine tuning of the db server.
So I recommend neither 1 nor 2.

Just:

```
SELECT * FROM `your_table` WHERE `any_field` = 'YOUR CRITERIA' LIMIT 300;
```

When your data overcomes 1,000,000 rows you should think about strong indexes optimization and maybe you'll have to create a stored procedure for complicated select. I assure you it's not PHP work in any case.

Comment: Ideally, I'd love to do it this way. Unfortunately, the table that I'm querying was not built for the type of queries I'm attempting right now. The piece of data that'll decide whether the row is required or not is hidden beneath a JSON string inside a particular field. That's why I can't query the database directly.

Comment: But, I like your idea from your comment below. Creating a buffer table. Let me see if I can implement a solution on those lines!

Answer (score 0):

As your question asks from Performance prospective, your both approaches would consume some resources. I would still go for `approach 1` in this case, as it doesn't make query to database again and again, if you generate query for each row i.e. 300-400 queries. When it comes to huge project designing, database always comes as bottleneck.

To be honest, both approaches are not good. Its good practice to have good database design and query selection. What you are trying to achieve could be done by suitable query.

Comment: I know both aren't good. But, I'm forced to choose between the two, because of poor database design. :) Hmm. Makes sense. Putting lesser load on the database server will be a better option, long term.

Comment: Fetching and transferring 100k rows from DB to PHP will take MUCH MORE  DB-server resources and time than simple select on DB side.

Comment: @ViacheslavDobromyslov Hmm. ok. Transferring 100k rows at once will consume more resources than 300 to 400 independent, smaller queries, fetching a single row at a time?

Comment: @om_deshpande If you use 400 independent queries then db will waste time on request planning and you will not be able to get properly sorted result. If somebody insert/update some rows you could miss them and the result will be inconsistent.
Another way to solve the problem is to create a temporary table and use it as a buffer.

Answer (score 0):

Using PHP to loop through the data is really a bad idea, after all, a database is **designed** to perform queries. PHP will need to loop through *all* the record, and doesn't use an index to speed things up; this is roughly equivalent to a 'table scan' in the database.

In order to get the most performance out of your database, it's important to have a good design and (for example) create indexes on the right columns.

Also, if you haven't decided yet what RDBMS you're going to use, depending on your usage, some databases have more advanced options that can assist in better performance (e.g. PostgreSQL has support for geographical information)

Pease provide some *actual* data (what kind of data will be stored, what kind of fields) and samples of the kind of queries / filters that will need to be performed so that people will be able to give you an **actual** answer, not a **hypothetical**